# Create class IntWritable error?

Tags: java, hadoop, error-handling, importerror

While I am writing my own Map reduce program, I am getting this type of error in the following line

Code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
```

Error:

Create a class InWritable in Package: org.apache.hadoop.io

I have successfully executed word count program in which the same line is present in the same eclipse, now also there is no error on that line in the word count program.

What is the meaning of that error? How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the error message is `Create a class InWritable in Package: org.apache.hadoop.io`?

Comment: yes. I am getting that error.

Comment: Do we need to add packages to each project separately?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by Adding following jar files from hadoop/lib to Java build path of the above said project,

hadoop-client-1.2.1.jar,

hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar,

hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar.